# mySQL - Count Distinct row based on criteria in one column

Tags: mysql, vb6, adodb

I have a table with the following columns:

```
    id          hcp_id          status
    1           10              True
    2           10              False
    3           10              True
    4           20              True
    5           20              True
    6           20              True
    7           30              False
    8           30              True
    9           30              True
```

The results should be:

```
    Results:

    hcp_id
           10 = 0
           20 = 1
           30 = 0
```

Basically, if all entries for a specific **hcp_id** has no **False** status, count it as one.  After which, sum all the results:

```
    Result = 0 + 1 + 0
```

Also, it has to work in **ADODB** with **mySQL ODBC** for **VB6**

Is this possible as well as doing it in a single query?

Other things to consider is speed since this will be done in a table with at least 14,000 or more records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For mysql you can do in this way ,but i have no idea how to write it for ADODB

```
SELECT 
 hcp_id, 
CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(`status` ='False')) =0 THEN 1
ELSE 0 END `all_true`
FROM
  t 
GROUP BY hcp_id
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1d12c/6)

Comment: Thank you!  This is indeed what I wanted.  I'll just need to tweak this for ADO